# how to append html to dynamically created html part

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

```js
function add_items()
        {
            var ingrediants_name = $("input[name='hidden_name[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
            mystat++;
        var my=mystat;
            console.log(my);
            
            
            
            $('#ingrdiants_table').append('<tr> <th class="no">'+my+'</th><td ><select class="selectpicker input-xlarge" name="ingredients_name[]" id="ingredients_name[]" style="width:200px;" >\n\
\n\
     \n\
</select>\n\
</td> <td><input type="text" name="ingrediant_quant[]" class="form-control"></td></tr>');
            //var selecter = $("input[name='ingredients_name[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
            
            var letters = "";
            for (i = 0; i < my; i++) 
            {
                for(j=0;j<ingrediants_name.length;j++)
                {
                    //$("#ingredients_name[0]").append('<option>'+ingrediants_name[j]+'</option>');
                    letters += '<option>'+ingrediants_name[j]+'</option>';
                }
                document.getElementById("ingredients_name[0]").innerHTML = letters;
            }
          
        }
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
    
                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content" style="width:700px;">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="add" onclick="add_items()">Add Ingredients</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <table id="ingrdiants_table" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                            <thead>
        
                                                <th>N</th>
                                                <th>Ingrediant Name</th>
                                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                                
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
        
                                            </tbody>
    
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="pencat">save</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Please help me to resolve this. I am creating select option dynamically on click with append in java script. I have assigned select option id="name[]",now  i want to assign option to all of select option box through append or something better. how can it work?

Comment: I don't really have a clue what you are asking, but my intuition tells me you want to read up on jQuery event delegation.  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Your snippet returns "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" when the "Add Ingredients" button is clicked, probably because you didn't add a reference to jQuery. Please edit the snippet so that it functions, and also describe, in as much detail as possible, both your expected results and your actual results. You will not receive many helpful responses if nobody understands your problem, so you also might want to see this: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)